# Multiple $match values in Mongoose Aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a working Mongoose aggregation query which contains:
`{ "$match": { "sumGroup": { "$in": group }, "sumId":5}},`

however I need `"sumId":5` to be dynamic.  I can get the value I want to use from `req.params.timesTableid` but I can't successfully use this in the query.

I have tried:
`{ "$match": { "sumGroup": { "$in": group }, "sumId":"$$req.params.timesTableid"}},`

and

`{ "$match": { "sumGroup": { "$in": group }, "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$sumId", "$$req.params.timesTableid" ] } } },`

but both of these come back with an empty results set.  Does anyone know how I can make this query dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is rather embarrassing.  The value of `req.params.timesTableid` is a string and of course my query needs a number.  `parseInt(req.params.timesTableid)` does the job.  Hope this answer saves someone else an hour or so of their life!